# Stop formula if a certain cell has a date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I ran into a problem with my Google sheet.
in the sheet Column "B" has an order date and Column "H" is counting days till today.
I want Column "H" to stop counting the day if Column"F" has a date.
Column "H" show day count till the date of column F
please see attached sample file.
[image: problem UI here]

Looking forward to your help

Comment: Columns F and H are hidden in this screenshot. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)?

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU WANT NOT TO USE YOUR FUNCTION WHEN DATE APPEARS IN COLUMN AND CONTINUE DOWN:**

You should work with datevalue and iferror function (isdate does not work with arrayformula).

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(
if(isblank(iferror(datevalue(B3:B23))),"your function","")
)
```

IF your formula is to count days passed since some date, try this:
[image]

```
={"Days passed";ArrayFormula(
if(isblank(iferror(datevalue(B4:B23))),today()-A4:A23,"")
)
}
```

****IF YOU WANT THIS FORMULA TO GO FROM THE TOP AND STOP WHEN DATE APPEARS.****
Core of the problem is how to check if data in this column is a date.
Then you have to use match formula to determine a row where the date is and stop arrayformula using array_constrain function.

First part (checking where is the data):

[image]

```
=match(FILTER(B3:B,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B3:B))),B3:B,0)
```

(assuming that data is in B3:B)

We know that arrayformula should go only to 9th row of data.

So you should use =array_constrain(arrayformula(function you need);row to stop;1)

And as we have a match formula for determining a row to stop, whole formula should look like this:

```
=array_constrain(arrayformula(function you need);match(FILTER(B3:B,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B3:B))),B3:B,0);1)
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your help. I don't want to stop the array formula for further rows. i want to stop counting in the same row when a shipping date entered.

Comment: OK. I got it. I've edited  and gave you second option. Maybe this one helps

Comment: I achieved it by doing IF($C3="",TODAY()-$B3,$C3-$B3)
but now if C and B are blank is is showing 44224 days while it should show nothing

Comment: Sorry by this
=ArrayFormula({"Days passed"; IF($U2:U="",TODAY()-$C2:C,$U2:U-$C2:C)})

Comment: Please take a look - I've added a formula counting days that passed since today